# Reading Json from Https

Tags: angular

I need to read a json from an https site, and I built an algorithm in my component:

```
customersObservable: Observable <any []>;
 constructor (private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
 ngOnInit () {
         this.customersObservable = this.httpClient
             .request ("GET", "https://urlmysite.com", {responseType: "json", myparams})
             .do (console.log);
     }
```

And in my html:

```
<ul * ngIf = "customersObservable | async as customers else empty">
   <li * ngFor = "let customer of customers">
....
   </ Li>
</ Ul>
<ng-template #empty> No Customers Yet </ ng-template>
```

Unfortunately, the 'customersObservable' object appears to have no data.
Am I wrong?

David

Comment: check it like: open the url with json in your browser. Are there some data to be displayed ?

Comment: Why don't you just do: `this.httpClient.get("https://urlmysite.com")`, Also if it is a different domain the other domain should be allowing CORS.